# Object mode and Edit mode is not the same?

Tags: export, unity

[image]

I'm add new Cube on Blender and scale,edit into brick...But when Export FBX and put it into Unity ...model is not change...why and how to make is same? Please ..some one help me?

Comment: After you edited the cube into a brick, and went back to object mode, did you apply the scale (press the CTRL key and the A Key simulaneously, then select either apply scale, or apply scale and roation)? From what you describe, it sounds like you most likely did not.

Comment: brasshat, what you say is correct.  Why not provide it as the answer?

Comment: @Vince he is not sure, thus he's asking. Or, maybe he's on hurry or else... see also https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/people-posting-their-answers-on-comments

Comment: @Phan Huy Did you know unity supports the native blendfile now?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data